# How to listen to inAppBrowser closed event

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

The following is the code that I am currently working with. I would like to understand how do I listen to the `inAppBrowser` close event? When some closes the inAppBrowser, the app should show some kind of alert message.

According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/) I have to use `browser.close()`, but this doesn't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-payment-information',
  templateUrl: 'payment-information.html'
})
export class PaymentInformationPage {

  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController ) {
    this.platform = platform;
  }

  paymentForm(){
      let browser = new InAppBrowser('https://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank', 'hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes&enableViewportScale=yes');
      browser.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are few things that is wrong in your code.

From the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/) `browser.hide()` doesn't do what you want to do.

> Hides an InAppBrowser window that is currently shown. Calling this has
>   no effect if the InAppBrowser was already hidden.

`_blank` replace it with `_system` because `_blank` opens in the inAppBrowser. You won't be able to listen for close event.

Now, you can subscribe to the browser and listen for it's events e.g.

```
//Events: loadstart, loadstop, loaderror, exit
browser.on('exit').subscribe(() => {
    console.log('browser closed');
}, err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: i have tried the solution, but am getting an error ".on" is not a function

Comment: If you dont have jquery or similar you can't use 'on'. Instead use:  
        var popupWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
 popupWindow.addEventListener('exit', function (event) {
  alert('user closed in app browser!');
 });

Comment: browser.on('exit').subscribe(function (event) {
}); i want to open in this window when debug. not open in new tab

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi you can use "_self " not "_blank" or "_system".

Comment: But I have problem, can I get last link accessed on browser?

Answer (score 2):

*I know it to late this issue was 3 years ago but the issue is an issue so here is the solution*

**1st import InAppBrowser**

```
import {InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

**2nd add to constructor()**

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser ) {}
```

**3rd Now you can use on('xxx') where xxx is the event you want
Events list:
'loadstart' | 'loadstop' | 'loaderror' | 'exit' | 'beforeload' | 'message' | 'customscheme'**

***In your case, you want to listen when inAppBrowser is closed check follwoing example:***

```
anyFunName(url){
let openBrowser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank');
openBrowser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
  console.log("inAppBrowser is closed now");
  // your action here when close inAppBrowser
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched in the InAppBrowser docs and there's nothing like a listener/promisse for a closed event, what you can do instead is using Platform's resume event, so when the InAppBrowser closes and the app is coming from background to active state it fires this method.

In [Ionic 2 API DOCS](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#resume) there's nothing saying how you can use it, but since you can subscribe to it then you can do something like this in your constructor (what probably wouldn't be good since the user can leave the app when in this page and come back) or inside your `paymentForm`method.

```
this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
  this.whatINeedToDoWhenUserIsBack();
});
```

Comment: did u not see 'on'

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify to Navneil Naicker's correct answer. If you don't have jquery, you would use `addEventListener` instead of `on`. And this can be done on the return value from `window.open`.

```
var popupWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
popupWindow.addEventListener('exit', function (event) {
    alert('user closed in app browser!');
});
```